# Push the current ItemsSource of a DataGrid to a stack

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, stack

My program has a DataGrid filled with information that, when a button is pushed, I would like to be pushed into a stack so it can later be popped out. How would I go about doing this? I've tried figuring out what type the stack would need to be, but I've had no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell us what (kind of) feeds you use for ItemsSource.

Comment: The source is a List<FileProperties>, which is an object of my own creation consisting of Filename, Filetype, Filesize, DateCreated and DateModified properties

Comment: Then `Stack<List<FileProperties>>` would be a little better.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... Keeps saying that there's invalid arguments, and that it cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FileProperties>'

Comment: Yeah... you lose info when assigning to ItemSource. `List<IEnumerable>` is good enough though.

Comment: IEnumerable seems to require a type of its own... What would I put in there? `FileProperties`?

Comment: Use the older non-generic version (`System.Collections.IEnumerable`). Or just stick with `object`.

Comment: Having it as Stack<System.Collections.IEnumerable> makes it all work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `Stack<object>`.